# Parsing a 2D JSON array in Android and then putting them in intents and getting their values in another activity

Tags: android, json

I need to parse a 2D array in Android and passing them as intent in another activity. How do I do that?

I am getting the following 2D array as a response from the server.

```
[
{
    "sno": "131",
    "email": "ruma.riwaz@gmail.com",
    "place": "43",
    "description": "",
    "image": "",
    "time": "1316156532"
},
{
    "sno": "130",
    "email": "ruma.riwaz@gmail.com",
    "place": "38",
    "description": "",
    "image": "",
    "time": "1316153291"
},
{
    "sno": "365",
    "email": "ruma.riwaz@gmail.com",
    "place": "86",
    "description": "",
    "image": "",
    "time": "1318427821"
},
{
    "sno": "129",
    "email": "ruma.riwaz@gmail.com",
    "place": "39",
    "description": "",
    "image": "",
    "time": "1316152314"
},
{
    "sno": "371",
    "email": "ruma.riwaz@gmail.com",
    "place": "90",
    "description": "",
    "image": "",
    "time": "1318502879"
},
{
    "sno": "370",
    "email": "ruma.riwaz@gmail.com",
    "place": "89",
    "description": "",
    "image": "",
    "time": "1318495237"
},
{
    "sno": "366",
    "email": "ruma.riwaz@gmail.com",
    "place": "86",
    "description": "",
    "image": "",
    "time": "1318427852"
},
{
    "sno": "126",
    "email": "ruma.riwaz@gmail.com",
    "place": "43",
    "description": "",
    "image": "",
    "time": "1316149489"
},
{
    "sno": "125",
    "email": "ruma.riwaz@gmail.com",
    "place": "43",
    "description": "",
    "image": "",
    "time": "1316148422"
},
{
    "sno": "168",
    "email": "ruma.riwaz@gmail.com",
    "place": "39",
    "description": "",
    "image": "",
    "time": "1316265504"
},
{
    "sno": "368",
    "email": "ruma.riwaz@gmail.com",
    "place": "87",
    "description": "",
    "image": "",
    "time": "1318480496"
},
{
    "sno": "174",
    "email": "ruma.riwaz@gmail.com",
    "place": "39",
    "description": "",
    "image": "",
    "time": "1316667799"
},
{
    "sno": "176",
    "email": "ruma.riwaz@gmail.com",
    "place": "39",
    "description": "",
    "image": "",
    "time": "1316670052"
},
{
    "sno": "252",
    "email": "ruma.riwaz@gmail.com",
    "place": "54",
    "description": "",
    "image": "",
    "time": "1317471220"
},
{
    "sno": "300",
    "email": "ruma.riwaz@gmail.com",
    "place": "39",
    "description": "",
    "image": "",
    "time": "1317964945"
},
{
    "sno": "299",
    "email": "ruma.riwaz@gmail.com",
    "place": "39",
    "description": "",
    "image": "",
    "time": "1317964703"
},
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Check this detailed Tutorial: http://pareshnmayani.wordpress.com/2011/09/06/android-json-parsing/

Comment: What you want exactly? check my answer.

Comment: i need to put the values in  intent and them get these values in another activity

Comment: @ekjyoy have you mentioned this anywhere in question? And check my answer, i have replied for preparing ArrayList of objects which is very much easy to implement and get the objects whenever you want.

Comment: my dear this is not a perfect way to ask question here, you should update the question with current need instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, **`myObject`** is the class that I have taken just for the reference and just defined getter and setter methods for all the above attributes inside this `myObject` class. And now when you are done with it, implement the below code to prepare an arraylist of all the items that your JSON contains.

```
      ArrayList<myObject> listObject = new ArrayList<myObject>();
      myObject obj = null;

      try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);
        for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length() ; i++)
        {
            JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            obj = new myObject();
            obj.setSno(jObject.getString("sno"));
            obj.setEmail(jObject.getString("email"));
            obj.setPlace(jObject.getString("place"));
            obj.setDescription(jObject.getString("description"));
            obj.setImage(jObject.getString("image"));
            obj.setTime(jObject.getString("time"));

         /* Add the list item object to the ArrayList. At the end you will be
            having an arraylist of all items that you have parsed. */

            listObject.add(obj);
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Have you ever tried this solution and displayed the same in listview? implement the click listener for listview and get the object at clicked position and pass it to another activity.

Comment: I dont want to display it on listview

Comment: @ekjyot then why do you want to parse JSON and send the parsed response to another activity? Instead pass the JSON response string and parse it inside the another activity.

Answer (score 1):

```
String json = "Set your JSON here";
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
    Strin sno = object.getString("sno");
    //Continue the parsing this way.
}
```

Comment: and how to get the values in the next activities which are put in the activity

Comment: you can pass values between activities thru intent:http://lovingandroid.blogspot.com/2011/08/passing-values-from-one-activity-to.html

Comment: that i know but in this case we will be getting  in arrays

Comment: you can pass array thru Bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library. It has simple toJson() and fromJson() methods that make it REALLY easy to work with JSON and Java objects.

A usage guide can be found [here](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote small databinding library:

https://github.com/ko5tik/jsonserializer

Which does it on the sport

Just pass GSON reader to it with proper class (taken from unit tests) :

```
 /**
  * unmarshalling of JSON array shall produce list
  */
@Test
public void testUnmarshallingOfJsonArray() throws InvocationTargetException, IOException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    // must be lenient
    source = new JsonReader(new StringReader("[{one:239},{two:555}]"));
    source.setLenient(true);
    final List<WithTwoProperties> list = JSONUnmarshaller.unmarshallArray(source, WithTwoProperties.class);

    assertEquals(2, list.size());
    assertEquals(239, list.get(0).getOne());
    assertEquals(555, list.get(1).getTwo());
}
```

(Unmarshall Array needs class   of array elements,  so in this case it will be
somethoing like (new String[]).class )

Comment: Correction:  This is not a 2d array, but just array of objects.   Just define bean containing proper fileds ( JsonSerializer can do some data conversion for you) an pass it to unmarshallArray as data type

Comment: Can You tell me in some more detail; pls if possible code for this?

Comment: I fixes included sample  ro display properly.  Code is in unit tests of JSONSerializer  project

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
        String str = "YOUR JSON STRING";
        try {
            JSONArray tempArr = new JSONArray(str);
            for(int i = 0; i < tempArr.length() ; i++)
            {
                JSONObject obj = tempArr.optJSONObject(i);
                Log.i("TAG",obj.getString("sno"));
                Log.i("TAG",obj.getString("email"));
                Log.i("TAG",obj.getString("place"));
                Log.i("TAG",obj.getString("description"));
                Log.i("TAG",obj.getString("image"));
                Log.i("TAG",obj.getString("time"));             
            }
        } catch (JSONException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
```