# JSON parsing on Android

Tags: android, json, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing a 2D JSON array in Android and then putting them in intents and getting their values in another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763786/parsing-2-d-json-array-in-android)

I am making an Android applications in which I am getting the following response. I need to parse this using JSON parsing and take these to next activity:

```
[
{
    "sno": "131",
    "email": "ruma.riwaz@gmail.com",
     "place": "43",
    "description": "",
    "image": "",
    "time": "1316156532"
},
{
    "sno": "130",
    "email": "ruma.riwaz@gmail.com",
    "place": "38",
    "description": "",
    "image": "",
    "time": "1316153291"
},
{
    "sno": "365",
    "email": "ruma.riwaz@gmail.com",
    "place": "86",
    "description": "",
    "image": "",
    "time": "1318427821"
},
{
    "sno": "129",
    "email": "ruma.riwaz@gmail.com",
    "place": "39",
    "description": "",
    "image": "",
    "time": "1316152314"
},]
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Wow you have create a Brand new account for asking the same question. Is your above account and question different from this question and account?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try searching it on Google or in StackOverFlow it self (this could be duplicate question)....

any way;
You should use either [Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) or [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)